# Set Path for *.fontspec file

Tags: fontspec, paths

According to Section 2.3 of the [fontspec documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) it is possible to select a font by creating a file like ⟨fontname⟩.fontspec.
Does this file always has to be in the root of the document or could I somehow set a path?

So my setup currently looks like this:

```
├── fonts/
│   ├── scala/
│   └── scala sans/
├── main.tex
├── scala.fontspec
└── scalasans.fontspec
```

which works fine. But I would prefer it like this:

```
├── fonts/
│   ├── scala/
│   ├── scala.fontspec
│   ├── scala sans/
│   └── scalasans.fontspec
└── main.tex
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this exact problem today. Unfortunately, you'll have to keep your fontname.fontspec file either in the current working directory, or a standard texmf location. The font directory or some subdirectory will not do.

Comment: There are ways aoround this, dependent on your system or TeX distribution. With TeXlive you can add a so-called "aux-tree" globally to your setup, which may point to a path relative to your current project. That way, you can have  per-project texmf trees in the way the question was asked.
This configuration can either be done via ``tlmgr`` or via other build tools, e.g. by using ``latexmk`` and a configuration file ``latexmkrc``. There is an equivalent for MikTex as well.