# place of *.fontspec files in TDS?

Tags: fontspec, tds

I am looking to install my custom working `.fontspec` file into a local texmf tree under debian.

I have found this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573586/53868 hinting that it is possible, however, I can't find the right place inside the TDS and the fontspec manual wasn't helpful with this regard, either.

The current directory structure I have tried:

```
<texmf-root>/fonts/truetype/
|- HelveticaNeueLTCom
|  |- HelveticaNeueLTCom-BdCn.ttf
|  |- HelveticaNeueLTCom-BdEx.ttf
|  |- HelveticaNeueLTCom-Bd.ttf
|  |- HelveticaNeueLTCom-LtCn.ttf
|  |- HelveticaNeueLTCom-LtEx.ttf
|  |- HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt.ttf
|  |- HelveticaNeueLTCom-ThEx.ttf
|  |- HelveticaNeueLTCom-Th.ttf
|- HelveticaNeueLTCom.fontspec
```

I intend to have the files installed system-wide, i.e. let `<texmf-root> = /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`.

The `HelveticaNeueLTCom.fontspec` file:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[HelveticaNeueLTCom]
{
    UprightFont = {*-Th},
    BoldFont = {*-Bd},
    Extension = {.ttf},
    FontFace = {lt}{n}{*-Th},
    FontFace = {l}{n}{*-Th},
    FontFace = {ltx}{n}{*-ThEx},
    FontFace = {mdc}{n}{*-LtCn},
    FontFace = {m}{n}{*-Lt},
    FontFace = {md}{n}{*-Lt},
    FontFace = {mdx}{n}{*-LtEx},
    FontFace = {b}{n}{*-Bd},
    FontFace = {bx}{n}{*-BdEx},
    FontFace = {bc}{n}{*-BdCn}
}
```

Usage in my `m(N)we.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{HelveticaNeueLTCom}

\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

*compilation needs to be done with `lualatex` or `xetex`.*

What I got working so far:

- When I compile using `latexmk` and set `ensure_path('TEXINPUTS', "./texmf//");`, and use `<texmf-root> = './texmf', i.e. move the fonts into my project directory, this compiles and works fine. The` .fontspec`` file is read and the variants are used correctly.
- Consequently, I assume my `.fontspec` syntax is correct.

Problems:

- apparently, the correct TDS path for fonts is given in setcion 3.2 of https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/info/tds/tds.pdf. I assume, that I do not need the distinction `local/public/vendor`.
- However, TDS does not specify where to put the `.fontspec` file, and neither does the `fontspec` documentation.

Question:

- Where do the `.fontspec` files go in a TDS?
- How can I properly debug this?

Comment: they are just tex code so you can put them anywhere in TEXINPUTS, the same as a local .sty or .fd (not the font path)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, that worked (with some additional steps). I had to manually remove the directories ``/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/`` and run ``luaotfload-tool -v -vvv -u``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just tex code so you can put them anywhere in TEXINPUTS, the same as a local .sty or .fd (not the font path)

Noted in comments, you may need to rebuild your luatex font cache (I'm surprised by that, actually as the fontspec file doesn't have anything that you couldn't have put in a normal document).

Comment: I see, this probably had to do with the experiments I did beforehand, where some form of ``.fontspec`` must have been available at some point, but not at a later time.